# how to convert perl regex to python?

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-3.x

I am trying to convert this regular expression from Perl to Python:

```
if ($line !~ /^\*NODE/i || $line !~ /^\*ELEMENT OUTPUT/i)
{
    print $line;
}
```

I have written this Python code but it fails:

```
if (re.search("^!\*ELEMENT OUTPUT | ^!\*NODE", line)):
   print line
```

Answer (score 4):

The exact translation is:

```
node_pattern = re.compile("^\*NODE", re.I)
element_pattern = re.compile("^\*ELEMENT OUTPUT", re.I)

if (not re.search(node_pattern, line) or not re.search(element_pattern, line)):
    print line
```

Depending on what you are trying to do the `or` in the middle might be better off as an `and` but I can't be sure without knowing more about the whole problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In python there is better way to do this then regular expressions:

```
if not line.lower().startswith ('*node') or not line.lower ().startswith ('*element output'):
    print (line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the logic of the original is wrong. I guess that the intention was to print only the lines that do not start or with `*NODE` or with `*ELEMENT OUTPUT` (case insensitive). However, the condition holds for any line. If it starts with `*NODE` then it does not start with `*ELEMENT OUTPUT` and vice versa. This way, the condition is always evaluated to `True`.

The conclusion, there must be `and` instead of `or` even in the original.

Also, you must use raw strings (like `r'your pattern'` in Python or you have to double the backslashes. I believe, you do not want to double backslashes in regular expressions.

You can try the following snippet:

```
import re

simulated_file_content = [
  'line 1\n',
  '*NODE line 2\n',
  'line 3\n',
  '*eLeMent Output line 4\n',
  'line 5\n',
  ]


rex = re.compile(r'^\*(NODE)|(ELEMENT OUTPUT)', re.IGNORECASE)


for line in simulated_file_content:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not rex.search(line):
        print line
```

It displays:

```
c:\tmp\___python\FaisalSashmi\so12153650>python a.py
line 1
line 3
line 5
```